# Fix deep links issues by verifying ownership of web associated with this path

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

When attempting to upload the application to the Play Console, I received an error about deep links.

```
Deep links not working

Users will not go directly to your app from links associated with this path, but will see the app picker or be directed to the web browser. Once you have fixed these issues and published a new version, users need to update their app before the links will work.
```

```
FIX DOMAIN ISSUES

4 domains failed validation
Fix domain issues by verifying ownership of web links associated with this path
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the docs, look at [Declare website associations](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks#web-assoc). In short you have to create `assetlinks.json` file and upload it on all the domains at this location `.well-known/assetlinks.json` e.g. `https://www.example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json`. This will validate websites ownership.
example file from docs:

```xml
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "com.example",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["14:6D:E9:83:C5:73:06:50:D8:EE:B9:95:2F:34:FC:64:16:A0:83:42:E6:1D:BE:A8:8A:04:96:B2:3F:CF:44:E5"]
  }
}]
```

**For debugging** - include your debug sha256 key, you can get it by running gradle task `signingReport`.

**For Production** - include sha256 key from google play console, you can find it in: Your App -> Settings -> Signing Config.